# Trying to use waypoints with JavaScript API

Tags: here-api

I'm new with MapHere, I see that with REST API side I can specify waipoints but I can't with JavaScript, I tried some parameters like 'via' but only admit one point:

```
var routingParameters = {
  'routingMode': 'fast',
  'transportMode': 'car',
  // The start point of the route:
  'origin': '36.8414197,-2.4628135',
  'via': '37.9923795,-1.1305431',
  // The end point of the route:
  'destination': '40.4167047,-3.7035825',
  // Include the route shape in the response
  'return': 'polyline'
};
```

I saw an example on the main page of javascript web but I can't use waypoints:

```
var router = platform.getRoutingService(),
  routeRequestParams = {
    mode: 'fastest;car',
    representation: 'display',
    routeattributes: 'waypoints,summary,shape,legs',
    maneuverattributes: 'direction,action',
    waypoint0: '52.5160,13.3779', // Brandenburg Gate
    waypoint1: '52.5206,13.3862'  // Friedrichstraße Railway Station
};
```

Throwing the following error:

```
{"title":"Malformed request","status":400,"code":"E605001","cause":"Error while parsing request: 'origin' parameter is required\n","action":"","correlationId":"1c7bd525-b8af-4989-83a9-ab07f26a8c33"}
```

So, how I can send request for use waypoints?

**EDIT**

I saw the problem, when the .js create the url encode the second `&via=`

```
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.18.1&apikey=***&routingMode=fast&transportMode=car&origin=50.1120%2C8.6834&destination=52.5309%2C13.3846&via=50.1234%2C8.7654%26via%3D51.2234%2C9.1123&return=polyline
```

If I decode `&` and `=` works perfectly

```
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.18.1&apikey=***&routingMode=fast&transportMode=car&origin=50.1120%2C8.6834&destination=52.5309%2C13.3846&via=50.1234%2C8.7654&via=51.2234%2C9.1123&return=polyline
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaScript API does not yet (as of library version 3.1.18.1) support passing multiple waypoints, meaning passing an array of points to the `via` parameter. Your best bet around this lack of support would be to use the Routing REST API directly:

```sh
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?
  origin=52.550464,13.384223
  &transportMode=car
  &destination=52.477545,13.447395
  &via=52.529791,13.401389
  &via=52.513079,13.424392
  &via=52.487581,13.425079
  &apikey={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm using the last version 3.1 and writing your code get the following message: `{"title":"Malformed request","status":400,"code":"E605001","cause":"Error while parsing request: \n\n\tInvalid location specification at '50.1234,8.7654&via=51.2234,9.1123'\n\tInvalid waypoint at '50.1234,8.7654&via=51.2234,9.1123'\n\tUnexpected input at '50.1234,8.7654&via=51.2234,9.1123'\n\tInvalid value for parameter 'via' at '50.1234,8.7654&via=51.2234,9.1123'","action":"","correlationId":"20af1e01-6e95-44fc-ad38-bfec2b5dc5dd"}`

Comment: If not already done, make sure to request the routing service with: `platform.getRoutingService(null, 8)`

Comment: Yes, I'm using routing service version 8.

Comment: I did some edits in my original question writting the problem, pls if you can take a look.

Comment: I see. I'd suggest using the Routing REST API directly, which accepts multiple `via` query parameters

Comment: Thanks for the approach, do you have some plans to implement this on next version? would be so useful.

Comment: I agree with you that it would be useful. I think it will be supported sooner rather than later, but I have no timeline :)